# MacBook Air Yosemite Crashes, changes its name to (my computer MacBookAir (2)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash

I have re-installed Yosemite on my MacBook Air because of frequent crashes, thought it would fix the problem

I did it several times

After a few days, it crashes and I have noticed that it changes my device name to the same name but with (2) this way:

MyComputer MacBookAir => MyComputer MacBook Air (2)

My device often crashes.
Any idea? The name change is not important per se.

Comment: Did you swipe the disk before re-installation?

Comment: can we have some crash reports/messages, or the Console log.

Comment: Didn't swipe disk

Comment: and Which Crash Report? there are many of them, most of them being related to my -i devices, not to my MAC; As for reports, there are so many too